# Protocol buffers add() method very slow using Python

Tags: python, binary, protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol buffers to create a very big message.

I have a *repeated* element with 200 subelements. And then each of this subelements have almost 2000 subelements in another *repeated* field.

The problem is that my code spends about 4.676 seconds executing protobuf add() method to add this submessages to repeated fields.

```
num_calls tottime  cumtime
427044    0.734    4.676    add()
```

I try creating a python list and then executing extend() method to add every object at a time. But the performance is worse, because extend() is making copies of each submessage:

```
num_calls tottime  cumtime
X          X       3.9    extend()
X          X       3.6    _init_ (creating submessage)
X          X       0.047  appending to python array
Total: 7.547s
```

Anyone have an idea of how improving performance here? Redefining a method or something? maybe using different methods?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's see an excerpt of the code doing this.  Something I can run and experiment with.

Comment: Are you using the C++-backed implementation or the pure-python implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your idea Kenton Varda.

I've been researching information about using a c-backed implementation of protocol buffers from python. I didn't know there was this option.

I found a good discussion about different ways of improving performance in Python and I will go for the c extension option. [Read discussion](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1026)

I hope this info help other people trying to boost performance.

Also, with protobuf 3.0.0 it seems there are improvements in this area.